# Disable drag actions in ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app which, on one page, uses touch to scroll down in a table. However, the default "draggableness" of the whole page interferes with what I want to achieve. How can I prevent the content from moving when dragging?
I only found answers about the sidemenu.

```
.
```

Example of draggable content: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/VLwLOG (just try to drag up/down on white background)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not circumvent the code requirements by including some arbitrary code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<ion-pane>` to wrap the entire page, and insert `<ion-scroll>` where you have content that you want to be able to scroll (such as the table). You just have to make sure to set the height of the scrollable area. If your page is wrapped in an `<ion-content>` element, it will be scrollable by default.

From the docs:

> If you'd just like to have a center content scrolling area, use
>   ionContent instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, this doesn't solve my problem. Scrolling works already on the table, it's just really messy due to the fact that sometimes the whole page goes up or down due to the fact that the whole content is draggable. I'm just looking for an option to disable the page's draggableness, since it's something I'm not using at all.

Comment: The whole page goes up and down because it's scrollable. Is it in an `<ion-content>` element? If so, that's why, and you can switch it for an `<ion-pane>` element instead.

Comment: If you want to use `<ion-content>` anyway, try giving it the attribute `scroll="false"`. That should disable scrolling within the element as well.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Yes, it was all wrapped by an `<ion-content>`. I changed it to `<ion-pane>` and now everything works smoothly. Thank you very much!